# Progressbar and combinations in Python

Tags: python, combinations, tk-toolkit, python-itertools, ttk

I am using itertools.combinations module to find a large number of combinations. While my program finds all its combinations (a lot of them) it checks for sum of every combination to be some number and then program store that combination in list.

```
from itertools import *
from math import *
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk


x = int(raw_input('Enter number of combinations: '))
z = int(raw_input('Enter sum number: '))


def combinator():
    comb = combinations(range(100), x)
    for i in comb:
        yield i

my_combinations = []
combination_s = combinator()
for i in combination_s:
    print i
    c = list(i)
    if fsum(c)==z:
        my_combinations.append(c)

print my_combinations

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('ttk.Progressbar')
pbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=300, mode='determinate', maximum = 100)
pbar.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to have ttk.progressbar that shows progress every time program evaluates sum of combinations. How can I do that?

Comment: so far your code does not include any `tk` at all. you should at least try something before coming here.

Comment: But i do not have a clue how to connect it to progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that increases the progress bar for every combination. It just waits for a short time, but you can easily change it to do some calculations in the for loop in `ProgBarApp.start` instead of `time.sleep`

```
from Tkinter import *
from itertools import combinations
import ttk
import time

class ProgBarApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = range(1, 20)
        self.combs = list(combinations(self.vals,3))
        self.n = len(self.combs)
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum = self.n+1)
        self.progressbar.pack()

    def start(self):
        for c in self.combs:
            self.progressbar.step()
            time.sleep(0.01)    
            root.update()
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
p = ProgBarApp()
root.after(0, p.start())
root.mainloop()
```